# How to get records located between two dates (month and day) for all the years in my table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I try to get the records located between two dates (month and day) for all the years in my table.
My table contains records during 50 years.

I can do this for one year:

```
SELECT*
FROM  mytable
WHERE "Date"  BETWEEN {D '1700-05-01'} AND {D '1700-07-31'};
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I am using Libreoffice Base connected to Ms Access...So I use standard SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE EXTRACT (month FROM "Date") BETWEEN 5 AND 7
AND EXTRACT (day FROM "Date") BETWEEN 1 AND 31;
```

There might be easier answers depending on your RDBMS.
Please consider naming your date fields something else than `"Date"`, which is usually a reserved keyword.

Edit: In MS Access, instead of `EXTRACT`, use the `DatePart` function:

```
DatePart("m", "Date")
DatePart("d", "Date")
```

If the only thing you want is "all the May months in all the years", then you can forget the "extracting per day" part of this answer, and only extract per month.

Edit:  **all records included in the month of may during the first fifty years off the 18th century**

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE EXTRACT (year FROM "Date") BETWEEN 1701 AND 1750
AND EXTRACT (month FROM "Date") = 5;
```

Knowing that, in MS-Access, `EXTRACT (year FROM "Date")` is `DatePart("yyyy", "Date")`, and `EXTRACT (month FROM "Date")` is `DatePart("m", "Date")`, you should be able to figure it out now :)

Comment: You really don't need `EXTRACT (day FROM "Date") BETWEEN 1 AND 31` in the WHERE clause, do you?

Comment: Not in the given example indeed, but I guess it needs to work in other cases, such as "from May 1st to May 25th". And if the intended case is "from July 14 to August 2", then the use of BETWEEN simply does not work and you need some AND/OR clauses.

@Wilcar, then you don't event need to add the "day" clause, and extracting the "month" part is enough, but that was not your original post :)

Comment: I want to extract all records included in the month of may during the first fifty years off the 18th century – Wilcar

Comment: Edited my answer to fit these new requirements :) I hope this helps, but I don't know MS-Access much.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you should be able to. The syntax must just be edited accordingly so that instead of doing it by month and day, you only do it between the years you want. If you wish to do it for one specific year, just specify the dates from January 1st to December 31st of the year you want.